# Creating a Macro to call a Winshuttle script that will automate Products entry into SAP

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I'm very new to VBA with basic knowledge of VB.net

I'm trying to create an excel Macro that will run a Winshuttle script to automate the introduction of Products into SAP. As of now, we need seven SAP transactions to complete the creation of a product in the system so I'm trying to automate every transaction with Winshuttle and link them into seven macro buttons in an excel sheet so that anyone can run them with a single click. I do need to keep every script separate for compliance reasons so making it so all seven run with a single button is not an option.

Winshuttle offers an option to export a Macro that allows the script to be called via Excel and I changed the basics such as the script location in the computer, the startrow, endrow, logcolumn, and runonrows values but now I'm getting the following error:

> An error has occurred while opening worksheet
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Can someone help please? Additionally what does

> 'Change ALF path as per requirement and accessibility of file.
>
> 'Change Sheet where data can be written

mean? Should I remove the " ' " before the three lines of code and change the file path? Is it necessary or an option?

The complete code is as follows:

```
'----------------------------------------------
' Macro to use runSHUTTLE addin with code
'----------------------------------------------
Sub RunSHUTTLEfile()
'
' RunSHUTTLEfile Macro
'
 Dim runSHUTTLEAddin, AddinObject
 
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
 ' GET ADDIN OBJECT FROM EXCEL
 Set runSHUTTLEAddin = Application.COMAddIns.Item("TxRunner.AddinModule")
 
 If runSHUTTLEAddin Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Unable to initialize object of runSHUTTLE addin"
    Exit Sub
 End If
 
 ' Get com object from addin object
 Set AddinObject = runSHUTTLEAddin.Object.TsMacros
 If runSHUTTLEAddin Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Unable to initialize com object of runSHUTTLE addin"
    Exit Sub
 End If
 
 ' Set the type of run from the following
 '   RunNow = 0,
 '   RunOnErrors = 1,
 '   StepByStep_StopOnAllScreens = 2,
 '   StepByStep_StopOnErrors = 3
 AddinObject.TypeofRun = 0
 
 ' Set the Run On Rows from the following
 ' AsInShuttleFile = 0,     // rows  as in SHUTTLE file
 ' Selected = 1,            // selected rows on active excel sheet
 ' Filtered = 2             // filtered rows on active excel sheet
 AddinObject.RunOnRows = 1
 
 Dim strShuttleFile As String
 
 ' open existing SHUTTLEfile to Run
 strShuttleFile = "C:\Users\310274697\Documents\WinShuttle\TRANSACTION\TRANSACTION scripts\Creation of Materials Scripts\2017.11.21 ZMM01U creation of materials BR9V.txr"
 AddinObject.OpenShuttleFile (strShuttleFile)
 
 AddinObject.StartRow = 2
 
 AddinObject.EndRow = 3
 
 AddinObject.LogColumn = "E"

 'Change ALF path as per requirement and accessibility of file.
 'Change Sheet where data can be written
 'AddinObject.SheetName = "Sheet3"
 'AddinObject.AlfPath = "C:\USERS\SASINGH\DOCUMENTS\WINSHUTTLE\TRANSACTION\ALF\WE6800_ANKUR.ALF"
 'AddinObject.ResultFileName = "C:\Users\SASINGH\Documents\Winshuttle\TRANSACTION\Data\Copy of Abs-ldcvb.xlsx"
 
 ' Call the Run Function to start uploading data
 AddinObject.Run


  Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

at the end of

> strShuttleFile = "C:\Users\310274697\Documents\WinShuttle\TRANSACTION\TRANSACTION scripts\Creation of Materials Scripts\2017.11.21 ZMM01U creation of materials BR9V.txr"
>    AddinObject.OpenShuttleFile (strShuttleFile)

"(strShuttleFile)" shouldn't be there. Eliminating that got rid of the error.

Now I'm seeing "Invalid procedure call or argument" so I'm off to spent another couple of hours figuring out what that means.